# can do this with JPA / Hibernate using from for fn name

Tags: java, jpa

```sql
SELECT col11,col12,col13
FROM table(schema.fn_name(param1,param2,param3))
ORDER BY col11,col12;
```

the query can display other additional field (xyz) as well, although there is no such column. I can do this with callable statement

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible alternate solution is native query that works perfectly